# how to get the lowest cost when arrange moveable jobs

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

it's a very hard dynamic programming question, and I want to share with you and we can discuss a little bit toward its solution：

You will put your new application to cloud server; you have to schedule your job in order to get lowest cost. you don't need to care about the number of jobs running at the same time on the same server. every job k is given by a release time sk, a deadline fk, and a duration dk with dk ≤ fk - sk.  This job needs to be scheduled for an interval of dk consecutive minutes between time sk and fk.  server company would charges per minute per server.  You only need one virtual server and you can save money moving jobs from sk to fk around to maximize the amount of time without running any jobs or, in other word, to minimize the amount of time running one or more jobs. using dynamic programming to solve problem. Your algorithm should be polynomial in n, the number of jobs.

Comment: Are we doing homework together?

Comment: Post what you've come up with so far

Comment: we can discuss here, and I don't want to talk this physically. do you have any clue for this.

Comment: no any clue so far. sadly

Comment: Step 1 is to prove or just appreciate that every job can start at some **si**.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: No. If you want to cheat on your homework fine, but you don't get to hide it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of minimizing busy time.

See Theorem 17 of [this paper](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2010/2890/pdf/44.pdf):

> Rohit Khandekar, Baruch Schieber, Hadas Shachnai, and Tami Tamir. Minimizing busy time in multiple machine real-time
>   scheduling. In Proceedings of the 30th Annual Conference on Foundations of Software Technology and Theoretical Computer
>   Science (FSTTCS), pages 169 – 180, 2010

For a description of a polynomial time algorithm.

The key is:

1. To realize there are only certain interesting times that need to be considered (if you have a schedule, consider delaying each busy interval until you hit a deadline for one of the jobs being processed)
2. To consider when the longest duration job is done.  This splits the problem into two pieces; before and after, which can be solved independently in the normal dynamic programming fashion.